# Solution of having another tag in html option tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a `<select>` tag with some `<option>` tags .
the problem is that i wanna have some other tag such as `<input type="number" />`
or `<span>` in the option tags but with a bit searching i found that it is not allowed to do it .
Also i found some other selectboxes such as Select2 or bootstrap selectbox but they didn't solve my issue as well .
whats is the soloution ?
any idea ?
thanks in advance

Comment: it's definitely something you can't do and, probably, you shouldn't do. What are you trying to accomplish? I'm sure that whatever that is, there must be a better way

Comment: @Carlo  Actually I wanna do it because in my senario the user should mention a number for each selected item . cause of this i like to have the number input close to select option .

Comment: is multiple select? if no, simple can you create a `<select>` with unique id and when user select one option appear an `input` for write a number.

Comment: thats a good idea but its multiple

Comment: it's better that you put the code that you try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after searching again and asking , i found no answer . so i made a popup to get the numbers